# How can I make an unordered_multimap in C++ between an int and a pair?

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, unordered-map, multimap

When trying to run the following code I get this compiling error
"error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for ‘template class std::unordered_multimap’ unordered_multimap m;"

Is there any way I can setup an  multimap? If not how can I do what I want to do? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int n = 100;
unordered_multimap<int, pair> m; //Error is in this line

for (int a = 0; a <= n; ++a)
    for (int b = 0; b <= n; ++b)
    {
        int result = (a*a*a) + (b*b*b);
        pair<int,int> p = {a,b};
        pair<int,pair> p2 = {result,p};
        m.insert(p2);
    } 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `unordered_multimap< int, pair< int, int > > m;` Notice that `pair` is a template and requires two template arguments to become a usable type.

Comment: Between an int and a pair ... of what? A pair is not a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `std::pair` isn't a type by itself, it's a template that "generates" types. You need to specify what type you want to "make" by specifying the 2 template argument types that it asks for.

Your use case shows that you want to have two ints as a pair so you should specify that everywhere:

```
unordered_multimap<int, pair<int, int>> m;
```

and

```
pair<int,pair<int, int>> p2 = {result,p};
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and straightforward response!

Comment: @EduardoDeLaGarza Accept if you find this post answers your question